# Multiple Common User Control but one .js file

Tags: asp.net

I have include a JS file in to a aspx page.
The host page has multiple instances of the user control.
and each user control has there own grid. i have defined a
Javascript variable in each UserControl to get the UserControl
Spcific Grid.
The JS file has miltiple common function written for Grid.
but i have a problem to access the User Control specific grid,
Is there a way to access user control specific grid?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of register a javascript variable, in the ascx, call functions in this way:

```
<script>
  doSomethingWithGrid('<%= MyGrid.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.NET is changing control id's in run time and this is makes difficult to acces in client (javascript). You can get client like `ControlName.ClientID`